# .push() in json results in replacing instead of adding arrays to my json variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, database

i am trying to add different elements into a json array, each element is consisting of many variables that are user input

```
 var Items = {
                id: `${ID}`,
                datestart: `${datestart}`,
                dateend: `${dateend}`,
                timestart: `${timestart}`,
                timeend: `${timeend}`,
                recurrences: `${userchoice}`,
                daily: `${daily}`
            };
```

this elements are stored in an array defined by

```
 var array = [];
```

but when i try to add the element inside the array it only add once and then update any different data that is inserted by the user

```
 array.push(Items);
```

when i use the .push() function it only keep on replacing the new elements with the already existing one inside the array.
I am pretty sure that there is a simple solution to this but i am not able to see through it.

EDIT:
the whole code that i am using is as follows:

```
var array=[];
var ID=document.getElementById("id");
// the same for the rest of the variables
var Items = {
                id: `${ID}`,
                datestart: `${datestart}`,
                dateend: `${dateend}`,
                timestart: `${timestart}`,
                timeend: `${timeend}`,
                recurrences: `${userchoice}`,
                daily: `${daily}`
            };
// then i am directly adding the items to the array
 array.push(Items);
// then i am displaying the result
  var jsonstring = JSON.stringify(array);
  console.log(jsonstring);
```

Comment: Can you include the actual code where you push `Items` into `array`? Just seeing individual lines out of context makes it tough to debug.

Comment: You need to create new objects every time. JS doesn't copy the object on assignment, only the reference to the object. And there's no need for the string interpolation syntax when you're only using one variable for the entire string.

Comment: Without seeing the details I can’t say for sure, but if you’re declaring the array in the same place you’re doing the push then it’s a new array each time. It’s not replacing the old one with the new one, it’s a cresting an entirely separate array.

Comment: Please provide a working snippet that *demonstrates* the problem - it's likely something quite simple but need the code your using to guide you.

Comment: i updated my question and added my full code, i have tried declaring the items variable directly under the array variable and then adding the attributes to it after i got them from the user but the same result.

Comment: In your code above, is this done in a loop?

Comment: *it keep[s] on replacing* - this implies you're calling `.push` more than once, but your "whole" code only has this just the one time.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for helping me out, as ray hatfield said i was declaring my array inside the same js file as the .push function.

the correct way of doing this is:

Main.js

```
var array=[];
```

addingtojson.js

```
var ID=document.getElementById("id");
// the same for the rest of the variables
var Items = {
                id: `${ID}`,
                datestart: `${datestart}`,
                dateend: `${dateend}`,
                timestart: `${timestart}`,
                timeend: `${timeend}`,
                recurrences: `${userchoice}`,
                daily: `${daily}`
            };
// then i am directly adding the items to the array
 array.push(Items);
// then i am displaying the result
  var jsonstring = JSON.stringify(array);
  console.log(jsonstring);
```